# How to turn off journaling in IRIS programmatically

Tags: intersystems-iris

How can I programmatically turn off journalling in a particular InterSystems IRIS database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input by Lucas Fernandes · Jul 27,2021

In Caché I use this:

```
set path = ##class(Config.Databases).Open("USER").Directory  

set database = ##class(SYS.Database).%OpenId($get(path))

do database.DisableJournaling()
set status = database.%Save()

do database.EnableJournaling()
set status = database.%Save()
```

Comment: What is *"Caché"*?

Comment: Caché is the previous generation DB from InterSystems before IRIS was released.
Something that is totally natural for an expert of his qualification